# how to: picture of 5 coordinates in 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing

I have been trying to make a tikzpicture illustrating 5 points in 3d where from one point they are 4 vectors going out to the other 4 points. I wonder if there is a way to make this picture look more like 3d.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
scale=3,
>=stealth,
point/.style = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = 1pt},
dot/.style   = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = .2pt},
]

%% Vanishing points for perspective handling
\coordinate (P1) at (-9cm,1.5cm); % left vanishing point (To pick)
\coordinate (P2) at (9cm,1.5cm); % right vanishing point (To pick)

%% (A1) and (A2) defines the 2 central points of the cuboid
\coordinate (A1) at (0em,3cm); % central top point (To pick)
\coordinate (A2) at (0em,-3cm); % central bottom point (To pick)

%% (A3) to (A8) are computed given a unique parameter (or 2) .8
% You can vary .8 from 0 to 1 to change perspective on left side
\coordinate (A3) at ($(P1)!.8!(A2)$); % To pick for perspective 
\coordinate (A4) at ($(P1)!.8!(A1)$);

% You can vary .8 from 0 to 1 to change perspective on right side
\coordinate (A7) at ($(P2)!.7!(A2)$);
\coordinate (A8) at ($(P2)!.7!(A1)$);

%% Automatically compute the last 2 points with intersections
\coordinate (A5) at
  (intersection cs: first line={(A8) -- (P1)},
            second line={(A4) -- (P2)});
\coordinate (A6) at
  (intersection cs: first line={(A7) -- (P1)}, 
            second line={(A3) -- (P2)});



%% Possibly draw back faces
\fill[gray!90] (A2) -- (A3) -- (A6) -- (A7) -- cycle; % face 6
\node at (barycentric cs:A2=1,A3=1,A6=1,A7=1) {\tiny };
\fill[gray!50] (A3) -- (A4) -- (A5) -- (A6) -- cycle; % face 3
\node at (barycentric cs:A3=1,A4=1,A5=1,A6=1) {\tiny };
\fill[gray!30] (A5) -- (A6) -- (A7) -- (A8) -- cycle; % face 4
\node at (barycentric cs:A5=1,A6=1,A7=1,A8=1) {\tiny };

\draw[thick] (A5) -- (A6);
\draw[thick] (A3) -- (A6);
\draw[thick] (A7) -- (A6);

\node (n0) at (0,0) [point, label = left:$S$] {};
\node (n1) at (1.2,1.7) [point, label = left:$R_{1}$] {};
\node (n2) at (-0.5, 1.2) [point, label = left:$R_{2}$] {};
\node (n3) at (1.35,-1.1) [point, label = left:$R_{3}$] {};
\node (n4) at (-0.2, -1.9) [point, label = left:$R_{4}$] {};

\draw[<-] (n1) -- node (a) [label = {below right:$d_{1}$}] {} (n0);
\draw[<-] (n2) -- node (b) [label = {above right:$d_{2}$}] {} (n0);
\draw[<-] (n3) -- node (c) [label = {above right:$d_{3}$}] {} (n0);
\draw[<-] (n4) -- node (d) [label = {above right:$d_{4}$}] {} (n0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: the tikzpicture]

Comment: try drawing dashed line from all 3 walls to all points.

Comment: another thing you could do: scale the dots according to their distance from the "observer"

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to actually draw in 3D which is possible with [tikz-3dplot](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot?lang=en) package, then a very simple solution is to fill planes with some very light colours. See the below picture.

[image]

This is the code for your case

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
scale=3,
>=stealth,
point/.style = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = 1pt},
dot/.style   = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = .2pt},
]

%% Vanishing points for perspective handling
\coordinate (P1) at (-9cm,1.5cm); % left vanishing point (To pick)
\coordinate (P2) at (9cm,1.5cm); % right vanishing point (To pick)

%% (A1) and (A2) defines the 2 central points of the cuboid
\coordinate (A1) at (0em,3cm); % central top point (To pick)
\coordinate (A2) at (0em,-3cm); % central bottom point (To pick)

%% (A3) to (A8) are computed given a unique parameter (or 2) .8
% You can vary .8 from 0 to 1 to change perspective on left side
\coordinate (A3) at ($(P1)!.8!(A2)$); % To pick for perspective 
\coordinate (A4) at ($(P1)!.8!(A1)$);

% You can vary .8 from 0 to 1 to change perspective on right side
\coordinate (A7) at ($(P2)!.7!(A2)$);
\coordinate (A8) at ($(P2)!.7!(A1)$);

%% Automatically compute the last 2 points with intersections
\coordinate (A5) at
  (intersection cs: first line={(A8) -- (P1)},
            second line={(A4) -- (P2)});
\coordinate (A6) at
  (intersection cs: first line={(A7) -- (P1)}, 
            second line={(A3) -- (P2)});



%% Possibly draw back faces
\fill[gray!90] (A2) -- (A3) -- (A6) -- (A7) -- cycle; % face 6
\node at (barycentric cs:A2=1,A3=1,A6=1,A7=1) {\tiny };
\fill[gray!50] (A3) -- (A4) -- (A5) -- (A6) -- cycle; % face 3
\node at (barycentric cs:A3=1,A4=1,A5=1,A6=1) {\tiny };
\fill[gray!30] (A5) -- (A6) -- (A7) -- (A8) -- cycle; % face 4
\node at (barycentric cs:A5=1,A6=1,A7=1,A8=1) {\tiny };

\draw[thick] (A5) -- (A6);
\draw[thick] (A3) -- (A6);
\draw[thick] (A7) -- (A6);

\node (n0) at (0,0) [point, label = left:$S$] {};
\node (n1) at (1.2,1.7) [point, label = left:$R_{1}$] {};
\node (n2) at (-0.5, 1.2) [point, label = left:$R_{2}$] {};
\node (n3) at (1.35,-1.1) [point, label = left:$R_{3}$] {};
\node (n4) at (-0.2, -1.9) [point, label = left:$R_{4}$] {};



\draw[fill, green, opacity=.1] (0,0) -- (1.2,1.7) -- (-0.5, 1.2);
\draw[fill, green, opacity=.1] (0,0) -- (-0.2, -1.9) -- (1.35,-1.1);
\draw[fill, red, opacity=.05] (0,0) -- (1.2,1.7) -- (1.35,-1.1);


\draw[<-,very thick] (n1) -- node (a) [label = {below right:$d_{1}$}] {} (n0);
\draw[<-,very thick] (n2) -- node (b) [label = {above right:$d_{2}$}] {} (n0);
\draw[<-,very thick] (n3) -- node (c) [label = {above right:$d_{3}$}] {} (n0);
\draw[<-,very thick] (n4) -- node (d) [label = {above right:$d_{4}$}] {} (n0);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the coordinate transformation macros available in Ti*k*Z that basically allow to define a new set of coordinate x, y and z as a function of the "old" system u, v as shown below:

[image]

I find this code less tricky and with less calculation:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\rot{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(180+\rot:1cm)},y={(-\rot:1cm)},z={(90:1cm)},scale=.7,>=stealth,thick]


\draw [fill=gray,draw=none] (0,0,0)--(10,0,0)--(10,5,0)--(0,5,0)--cycle;
\draw [fill=gray!50!white,draw=none] (0,0,0)--(10,0,0)--(10,0,15)--(0,0,15)--cycle;
\draw [fill=gray!30!white,draw=none] (0,0,0)--(0,5,0)--(0,5,15)--(0,0,15)--cycle;
\draw (0,0,0)--(10,0,0) (0,0,0)--(0,5,0) (0,0,0)--(0,0,15);


\node [fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] (pt0) at (5,0.5,5) {};
\node [fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] (pt1) at (0,1,10) {};
\node [fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] (pt2) at (9,0,9) {};
\node [fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] (pt3) at (0,2,1) {};
\node [fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] (pt4) at (8,2,0) {};

\draw [->] (pt0)--(pt1) node [pos=.5,right] {$d_1$};
\draw [->] (pt0)--(pt2) node [pos=.5,right] {$d_2$};
\draw [->] (pt0)--(pt3) node [pos=.5,below] {$d_3$};
\draw [->] (pt0)--(pt4) node [pos=.5,right] {$d_4$};

\node at (pt0) [left] {$S$}; 
\node at (pt1) [above] {$R1$}; 
\node at (pt2) [left] {$R2$}; 
\node at (pt3) [right] {$R3$}; 
\node at (pt4) [below] {$R4$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and this is the output:

[image: Image with 3d transformation and angle=20]

Note that I defined a number called `\rot`. If you change its value up to 30 (for example) you will automatically get another perspective. Moreover, if you want more depth, you may also draw dashed lines.
Another thing you can do, since the lack of depth is mainly due to the small changes in y-coordinate, you may want to change the scale of that direction, for example `y={((-\rot:3cm))}`

[image: More depth with dashed line and different perspective]

by simply adding to the above's code these few lines (note `\def\rot{30}` in the preamble):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(180+\rot:1cm)},y={(-\rot:3cm)},z={(90:1cm)},...]
...
\draw [dashed] (pt1)--+(0,-1,0) (pt1)--+(0,0,-10);
\draw [dashed] (pt2)--+(0,0,-9) (pt2)--+(-9,0,0);
\draw [dashed] (pt3)--+(0,-2,0) (pt3)--+(0,0,-1);
\draw [dashed] (pt4)--+(-8,0,0) (pt4)--+(0,-2,0);
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Didn't notice that Love Grover had already suggested dashed lines.. You can also couple CroCo answer that is definitely great.